# ASP.NET C# problem with Table and SQL logic

Tags: c#, .net, sql, logic

Hey I have 3 tables called STUDENT, COURSE and ENROLLMENT. STUDENT has a PK of S_ID(student ID) and COURSE has PK of C_ID(course ID). In enrollment it only has S_ID and C_ID. I have an object data source to show all the students name (in text, and S_ID as the value) in a drop down menu and it will show which courses he is registered in when clicked, using a datagrid and another object data source. I wont to have the student to have multiple courses to be registered too, but I cant do that because you cannot have the same ID in the COURSE table, so every student is only registered to one course.

Is there some sort of option to have same ID's in a table?

If not, then I must some how manipulate the string in C_ID in the COURSE table because all the courses start with ISDVXXX or ITSXXXX or HGFXXXX. This may be hard to understand but hopefully someone will help.

An example may help
So if a student named Joe with a S_ID of 123 is registered to ISDV, he will be registered to all the courses that start with ISDV. But my problem is that my COURSE table has to have unique ID for each course such as ISDV123, ISDV346, ISDV395 etc... so this also ruins my enrollment table because I cannot simply have ISDV in there, it needs a specific course but he is registered to all of them. Any more clarification will be given :P Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to solve is a multi-valued attribute problem. Basically, you have two tables where one (`students`) has a primary key which is a foreign key in another table (`classes`). You don't want to have multiples of the same class in the `classes` table, but you do want a `student` to be able to have multiple `classes`.

So, there is a very simple fix, you create another table which contains at least these two columns: student_id and class_id. This way, you could have a single `class` that multiple `students` are linked to, and also multiple `classes` to which a `student` can be linked to.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a many to many relationship - i.e. a single student can have multiple courses, and a single course can have multiple students.  So your link table (is this what you intended enrollment for?) should have two columns, one for the course ID and one for the student ID.

So if you had student 123 and student 234, and courses ABC and XYZ, your table would look something like:

```
S_ID   C_ID
123    ABC
123    XYZ
234    ABC
```

Now, for your PK on enrollments you could either use a composite key, or add a unique integer RowId (Identity or HiLo algorithm).

In that case, your enrollment table would look something like this:

```
S_ID    C_ID     RowID
123     ABC      1
123     XYZ      2
234     ABC      3
```

Then, to see what classes a student was in, you could do something like

```
Select * from courses c 
 inner join enrollments e 
 on c.C_ID = e.C_ID 
 AND e.S_ID = @StudentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Enrollment table stands for the m:n relationship between the Studend and Course tables.

For instance your student with S_ID = 69 is Enrolled to the Courses with C_ID = ISDVXXX , C_ID = ITSXXXX, C_ID = HGFXXXX
A Student can be Enrolled to more Courses and more Students can be Enrolled to the same Course, that's why you have your Enrollment table. In our example, the Enrollment will have the following rows:
(69, ISDVXXX), (69, ITSXXXX), (69, HGFXXXX).
If later a student with the S_ID = 96 joins to the Course with C_ID = ISDVXXX, the following will be the new rows of the Enrollment table:
(69, ISDVXXX), (69, ITSXXXX), (69, HGFXXXX), (96, ISDVXXX).
The important thing to understand here is that each row in the Enrollment table stands for a Student Enrolled to a Course and there is no need to other fields than the ID of the Student and the ID of the Course, for these two fields together identify an Enrollment.